# RegEx to extract partial string

Tags: c#, regex

So simple but I'm struggling, I do RegExp every 2 years or so , so I'm rusty

I have these two url strings 
http://localhost:58876/Products/Product1
https://localhost:58876/Products/Product1

The result I want is

localhost:58876

Basically remove the http(s):// and everything after the first single / so I end up with the domain with or without the port number

P.S: I'm working with C#

Comment: Which flavor? What did you try?

Comment: If you're using PHP, [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (tested int notepad++):

```
(\w+:\d+)
```

Comment: This works for the specific example (it’s nicely brief), but not for hostnames containing hyphens, for instance, and not for hosts without a port. And not for crazy stuff like `http://user:pass@host.com:8080/path`.

Comment: ([\w\d\:\@\.]+:[\d]+)  try this:)

Comment: little fix - since port is not always present - \/\/([\w\d\:\@\.]+:?[\d]?+)
this "\/\/" on the beginning it is double slash. It will find all matching strings with //. Later you can substract what you want starting from position '2' and ending on string.length.

Comment: This is my C#

                http://localhost:58876/Products/Product1
                var regex = new Regex(@"(\w+:\d+)") ;
                return regex.Match(url).Value;

Comment: scroll down - I added another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just match anything but a slash: `/^https?:\/\/([^\/]+)\/.*$/`

```js
var url = 'http://localhost:58876/Products/Product1';
var match = url.match(/^https?:\/\/([^\/]+)\/.*$/);
if(match&&match.length>0)document.write(match[1]);
```

Even shorter: `/\/\/([^\/]+)/`. Note that there are (a lot) better ways to parse URLs. Depending on your platform, there’s PHP’s [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.parse-url.php), NodeJS’s [`url` module](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html) or libraries like [uri.js](https://gist.github.com/jlong/2428561) that handle the many faces of valid URIs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex to split the URL:

> ((http[s]?|ftp):/)?/?([^:/\s]+)(:([^/]*))?((/\w+)*/)([\w-.]+[^#?\s]+)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?

The RegEx positions 3 and 5 are those you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
   (^[^h]|\/\/)([\w\d\:\@\.]+:?[\d]?+)
```

then in c#:

```
string address = ...
char[] MyChar = {'/'};
string NewString = address.TrimStart(MyChar);
```

EDIT: also worked with localhost:58876/Products/Product1
!